# How would you call a navigation option that contains chats, call history and booked calls?

Tags: navigation, labels

I am designing an app that allows users to connect with experts from any field via chat or video calls. On the navigation bar there will be an option that contains the chats between user and experts, recent calls and booked calls. "Communication" seems a very long name, do you have other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Some more context would be helpful, like a mini-narrative that describes how the user is even going to encounter this navigation option in the first place. What's an example of something that would motivate them to browse the navigation at all?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an open card sort (https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/card-sorting.html) with your users to determine if they would group them in that way and if they would how they would label the grouping.